# Python appending elements of a list to a string

Tags: python

I have a python list:

```
myList = [202,230,50]
```

And I want to implode them into a string using whatever character I like, something like this to be outputted:

`"202,230,50"` or IO might like to have it like this: `"202-230-50"`

There is a similar function in PHP called `implode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [join method of strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
",".join(map(str,mylist))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` to convert each element to a string, and `join` to join the strings with any separator:

```
",".join(map(str,myList))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'.'.join([str(i) for i in myList])
```

We can even acheive this using list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Ramachandra's answer is nice.

```
','.join(str(i) for i in myList)
```

this one will also work nicely. No need to worry how map works. Just convert each elements as string and pass it to join function.

Answer (score 0):

more elaborative way:

```
>>> myList = [202,230,50]
>>> result = '"' + str(myList[0]) + "," + str(myList[1]) + "," + str(myList[2]) + '"'
>>> print result
"202,230,50"
```